# Another way in creating a CreateOrReplaceTempView in pySpark dateframe

Tags: pyspark

I have created a join condition using spark.sql, and created a tempview on the particular dataframe created. But, I have getting comment from architect to not to create temp view, go with dataframe itself. So, how can I achieve below things in another way of coding:

```
df1 = spark.sql(" select a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2,
                "rank() over(partition by b.bkeyid order by load_time desc) as rank "
                "from table1 a inner join table2 b "
                "on a.bkeyid = b.bkeyid")

df2 = df1.where(df1.rank == lit(1))   # Using rank to get most current records from the table b
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("new_table")
```

From the new_table, I have to join the same with another table3 like:

```
df3 = spark.sql(" select a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2,
                "rank() over(partition by b.bkeyid order by load_time desc) as rank "
                "from new_table a inner join table3 b "
                "on a.bkeyid = b.bkeyid")

df4 = df3.where(df1.rank == lit(1))
df4.createOrReplaceTempView("new_table2")
```

And I have to use new_table2 to create a target table using the provided mapping logic.
the thing is how can I achieve the above sql coding in another format. Please help me in updating my coding part??
THANK YOU

Comment: Look for dataframe API examples, and spark sql functions there. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use dataframe API's to invoke same instead of SQL queries.
As it is not possible to write the exact code for you but i am providing the second part of query in question or if needed you can change you first query in similar way

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df1 = spark.sql(" select * from (select a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2,
                rank() over(partition by b.bkeyid order by load_time desc) as rnk 
                from table1 a inner join table2 b 
                on a.bkeyid = b.bkeyid ) c where c.rnk=1")

table3_df =  spark.sql(select * from table3)


new_df2=df1.join(table3_df,df1.bkeyid=table3.bkeyid).select('col1','col2','col3','col4').withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy(df1['bkeyid']).orderBy(df1['load_time'].desc())))
new_df3=filter(new_df2['rank']==1).select('col1','col2','col3','col4').show()
```

Comment: HI,I have tried it. But I'm stuck with the error : 
**rank not found**.


`df_new = df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"), a.id = b.id, 'inner').select(a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2).withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy(b.col3, b.col4).orderBy(b.col5.desc(), b.col6.desc())))`

Please let me know where in the query you see any mistake???

Comment: how  you were able to query previously with rank function ?

Comment: Actually, i tried `spark.sql("with sql query")` as provided in my question. It is working but, i recommended to use in dataframes way... but im getting error when excuting as per your idea.

Comment: Add from pyspark.sql.functions import *  from pyspark.sql.window import Window

Comment: Everything i have imported as required, but getting again the same error. May be in the partition by or order by i have syntax error i guess.